# SimpleFormIterator focus first field when ADD

Tags: react-admin

We are using SimpleFormIterator inside ArrayInput like follows (as example)

```
<ArrayInput source="backlinks">
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <DateInput source="date" />
        <TextInput source="url" />
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

But when clicking "ADD" to add new fields it is still focused in "ADD" button. Is there any way we can focus on first added field after clicking "ADD"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an `autoFocus` prop on the `DateInput`, however, it means the first item will be focused automatically too in an Edit form which is probably not what you want.

I think this should be the job of the `SimpleFormIterator`. Can you please open a feature request issue on react-admin repository ?

In the mean time, you can make your own form iterator which would handle the focus.

Comment: Thank you. We needed some more features, eg. adding fields automatically when all existing fields filled. So we decided to use our own SimpleFormIterator.